# Why .has .vscode folder been generated in my GitHub repo?

Tags: flutter, github, visual-studio-code

So, I started my Flutter project with VScode but later I completed the whole project from Android Studio and have now pushed it from Android Studio into my Github repo. In my GitHub repo, the .vscode folder (refer to the snapshot added) has been generated. Is this something[image] I should be worried about and try removing it? I'm a newbie at Flutter and so kind of too meticulous about my codes. (^-^;)

Answer (score 2):

No that's normal and automatically generated by vsCode

If it bothers you can simply ignore it using .gitignore in your project folder.

Comment: Note that `.gitignore` does not apply to files already committed to a repo - so if they are unwanted they need deleting.